# Is there any way to get the results of a PromiseList if it times out

Tags: grails, groovy, concurrency, future

I have a PromiseList in Grails that has a list of promises. If I request the value with a time out value, will I still get the results, of the non-timed out futures, if the timeout stopped the promise list?

Comment: The short answer is no. You will not get any of the results as the timeout will cause an exception to be thrown and thus onComplete will not get called for the list of promises.

Comment: Do you know of an alterantive? If so please submit this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the short answer is "No, there is no way to get partial results when some of the promises in your promise list succeed and one or more fail." This is because a list of promises is considered to succeed or fail as an entire unit. Any exception, timeout included, will cause `onError` to be called instead of `onComplete`.

The only alternative, if you need individual results which are not dependent upon other promises is to use individual promises instead of a list.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get a maximum wait time for the entire group? 

Seems like a list of promises where I all say .get(30 Minutes) 5 times would result in 5*30 Minutes upper bounds.

Comment: No, each one would have a maximum of 30 minutes, and in reality you need to be most concerned about the minimum. E.g. 30, 30, 20 will cause an exception when 20 is exceeded. I assume you are using Async Promises and not Sync Promises (e.g. onComplete/onError vs waitAll), correct?

Comment: It would be to use Async promises yes.